# CodeIgniter Form Validation Matches Label

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is it possible to change the output of the `matches` call when running form validation in CodeIgniter?

I'm validating a password against a confirm password box.

```
array(
    'field' => 'userPassword',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[userConfPassword]'
)
```

But when the error is triggered it prints out:

```
The Password field does not match the userConfPassword field.
```

The user has no idea was `userConfPassword` means and I'd like to change that to something more friendly. Reading the docs I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can override the default message:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'the two passwords do not match|');
```

or some other message like that :).

I usually use that message for the "confirm password" only, though, so I set the normal password field as required and that's all, while for the confirm I have it to match the password entered, not the otherway around (or both). But that's just matter of taste I think.

For the record, it's written in this [paragraph of the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors).

Comment: Perfect! It never occurred to me that you could overwrite the existing message. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
array(
    'field'   => 'userPassword', 
    'label'   => 'Password', 
    'rules'   => 'trim|required|matches[userConfPassword]'
),
array(
    'field'   => 'userConfPassword', 
    'label'   => 'Confirm Password', 
    'rules'   => 'trim|required'
)
```

When the error is triggered it prints out:

> The Password field does not match the Confirm Password field.